# How to check whether Dictation is enabled in iOS Keyboard.?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, xcode6.4

I have to show an Image highlighting the Mic icon in iOS keyboard saying "Tap here to speak". But the Mic icon won't be displayed if dictation is disabled in Keyboard settings.

My aim is to check whether dictation is enabled at the time of launching the app. If not, I want to show a prompt to Enable Dictation from "Settings>KeyBoard>Enable Dictation"

Is there any way to check whether dictation is enabled when the app is launched.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is that checking whether the dictation is enabled **is not possible**.

Currently there are only few things that developers can play with in terms of dictation. They are defined in [`UITextInput Protocol`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009415-CH1-SW59). Sadly, what you're looking is not there.

Comment: So, there is no way to check the status of dictation through code.? 
Speech to text is extensively used in my App.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you cannot check whether its enabled.