# How can I programmatically check whether Dictation is enabled in tvOS?

Tags: tvos, siri-remote, tvos11

Is there any way to programmatically check whether dictation is enabled in tvOS (Siri remote)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not yet possible** in tvOS, [nor in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33781869/3151675).

For more information, check out the documentation of [`UITextInput`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput).

Comment: Actually, this is not directly related to UITextInput. For tvos, this is another user experience. For example in my case when the user opens search screen I want to warn users that they can use our application better with dictation. Anyway your answer is correct.

Comment: @mgyky My suggestion would be displaying that notice anyways, it's useful information.